# Generating random samples from normal distributions with parameters coming from a list

Tags: probability-or-statistics, sampling

```
MustarandSigmastar = Join[Mustar, VectorofSigmastar];
    z = Table[
       RandomVariate[
        NormalDistribution[MustarandSigmastar[[i]], 
         MustarandSigmastar[[j]]], n], {i, 1, m}, {j, m + 1, 2m}];
```

How to generate only m pairs of parameters? Thanks

Comment: Which pairs do you want? Do you want pairs like `{first, 1+mth}, {second,2+mth}, etc`? Also, please fix your code by providing definitions for all symbols. Without this, we're left making our own test cases and guessing what those should be for your context. And speaking of test cases, sample inputs with expected outputs would make it even clearer what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: Please post an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = 10;
mustar = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m]
sigmastar = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m]
z = MapThread[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#1, #2]] &, {mustar, sigmastar}]
```

Make `RandomVariate` pick as many as you wish. If you meant that you wanted existing parameter lists to be randomly paired, just replace `mustar` with `RandomSample@mustar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m = 5;
n = 4;

MustarandSigmastar = RandomReal[1, 2 m];

param =
  RandomChoice[
   Outer[{#1, #2} &,
     MustarandSigmastar[[;; m]],
     MustarandSigmastar[[m + 1 ;;]]] //
    Flatten[#, 1] &,
   m];

z = RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution @@ #, n] & /@
  param

(* {{0.707468, 0.736669, 0.708138, 0.721982}, 
    {0.40102, 0.430933, 0.425616, 0.414167}, 
    {0.557164, 0.480605, 0.523246, 0.462627}, 
    {0.711562, 0.710971, 0.780158, 0.665663}, 
    {1.17702, 1.01058, 0.908726, 0.706781}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MustarandSigmastar = Inner[List, Mustar, Sigmastar, List];
z = Table[
   RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[MustarandSigmastar[[i]][[1]], 
     MustarandSigmastar[[i]][[2]]], n], {i, 1, m}];

(This is how I addressed it.)
```

Comment: Simpler and more idiomatic approaches are available.